# Passing 2D array as class parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I am trying to set up a class that initializes with a 2d array of an unknown size at compile time. I figured the best way to do this would be to pass the array as a pointer. This works as expected with a 1d array, but when I try to do the same with a 2d array. I get an error that states that it cannot convert argument 2 from 'char [3][3]' to 'char*'. Does anyone have a simple explanation on how I can get this to work? Here is my code.

###### TestClass.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class TestClass
{
public:

    std::string name;
    char *data;
    TestClass(std::string name, char *data);
};
```

###### TestClass.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass::TestClass(std::string name, char *data)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->data = data;
}
```

###### Main.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"

int main()
{
    char TestArray[3][3] = {{ 'A', 'B', 'C' },
                            { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
                            { 'G', 'H', 'I' }};

    TestClass Test("TestName", TestArray);
    std::cout << Test.data[2] << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The TestClass constructor doesn't take a 2D pointer, do you want to write a new constructor that takes a 2D pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a 2D array by passing the address of the first element:

```
TestClass Test("TestName", &TestArray[0][0]);
```

But how is `TestClass` supposed to know the dimensions of the array? There is no way to query the data or to guess. You have to also pass `num_rows` and `num_cols`.

But then I see:

```
std::cout << Test.data[2] << std::endl;
```

So now you want the 2D array to be a 1D array of C-style strings? That's is not what your data represents.

You really should forget about all the C-style cruft and use modern C++ construct. Use `std::vector<std::string>` to store a variable number of strings.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Made an array with std::vector<std::vector<char>> and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the constructor's second parameter is of type `char*` but you're passing a 2D array `TestArray` which will **decay** to `char (*)[3]` and since there is no implicit conversion from `char(*)[3]` to `char*` you get the mentioned error.

To **solve** this you can either make the second parameter of the constructor to be a pointer to an array of size `3`(but then you'll also have to change the type of `data`) or better yet use `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: 'std::vector<std::vector<char>>' seemed to work for me. Thanks!